# How to join and count with multiple condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

i have 2 tables :

```
table1(id, name)
1233    AAA
3424    BBB
4345    CCC
4342    DDD
1243    RRR
3453    GGG
```

```
table2(id,date,status)
1233    01/07/19    1
3424    01/07/19    1
4342    01/07/19    2
1243    01/07/19    1
4342    01/07/19    1
4345    02/07/19    2
1243    02/07/19    1
1233    02/07/19    1
4345    03/07/19    1
4342    03/07/19    2
1233    03/07/19    1
4342    04/07/19    2
4345    04/07/19    2
4342    04/07/19    1
1243    04/07/19    2
```

15 ROW

i have tried this code

```
SELECT    rn.id, name, NVL(cnt, 0) jum
    FROM     table1 rn
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   id, COUNT(id) AS cnt
               FROM     VIEW_AKTIFITAS
               WHERE extract(year from date)=2019
               AND extract(month from date)=7
               GROUP BY id,extract(month from date) n ON n.id= rn.id
```

i want to get this result
how to count the status entry in table 2

```
RESULT
ID  COUNT_STATUS_1 COUNT_STATUS_2 TOTAL_COUNT
1233    2           0       2
3424    2           0       2
4345    1           2       3 
4342    2           3       5
1243    2           1       3
3453    0           0       0
```

please help me to solve this problem.. thanks

Comment: For the very first id, 1233, I count three rows with status 1. Why does your "desired result" show 2 instead of 3? Is that just a mistake, or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: its just my mistake .. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join `table2` to `table1` and then use conditional aggregation to get the different counts for the two status.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       count(CASE
               WHEN t2.status = 1 THEN
                 1
             END) count_status_1,
       count(CASE
               WHEN t2.status = 2 THEN
                 1
             END) count_status_2,
       count(t2.status) total_count
       FROM table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table2 t2
                      ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: thanks finnaly get result as i need. this is my final query

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11.1 and higher, you can use the `PIVOT` operator to do the aggregation. Something like this:

```
select id, name, count_status_1, count_status_2, 
       count_status_1 + count_status_2 as total_count
from   (select t1.id, t1.name, t2.status from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
                                                        on t1.id = t2.id)
pivot  (count(*) for status in (1 as count_status_1, 2 as count_status_2))
order  by id   --  if needed
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample code, you seem to want:

```
SELECT rn.id, rn.name, NVL(cnt, 0) jum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status_2,
       COUNT(a.status) as total
FROM table1 rn LEFT JOIN
     VIEW_AKTIFITAS a
     ON a.id = rn.id AND
        a.date >= DATE '2019-07-01' AND
        a.date < DATE '2019-08-01'
GROUP BY rn.id, rn.name;
```

You do not need a subquery for the `LEFT JOIN`.  The date comparisons are better done using direct date comparisons.  Oracle allows you to use ISO-standard date formats with the `DATE` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

> this is my final code

```
SELECT t1.nip, t1.nama_pegawai,
           count(CASE
                   WHEN t2.status = 1 
                    and t2.tahun=2019
              and t2.bulan=7
                   THEN
                     1
                 END) count_status_1,
           count(CASE
                   WHEN t2.status = 2 
                    and t2.tahun=2019
              and t2.bulan=7
                   THEN
                     1
                 END) count_status_2,
           count(CASE
           WHEN  t2.tahun=2019
              and t2.bulan=7
              THEN 1 END
            ) total_count
           FROM VIEW_PEGAWAI t1
                LEFT JOIN VIEW_AKTIFITAS t2
                          ON t2.nip = t1.nip
              where t1.opd_id=14  
              and T1.JENIS_PEG<>3

                          group by t1.nip,t1.nama_pegawai
```